# Evaluate array at specific subarray

Tags: python, numpy

I warn in advance: I may be utterly confused at the moment. I tell a short story about what I actually try to achieve because that may clear things up. Say I have `f(a,b,c,d,e)`, and I want to find `arg max (d,e) f(a,b,c,d,e)`. Consider a (trivial example of a ) discretized grid `F` of `f`:

```
F = np.tile(np.arange(0,10,0.1)[newaxis,newaxis,:,newaxis,newaxis], [10, 10, 1, 10, 10])
maxE = F.max(axis=-1)
argmaxD = maxE.argmax(axis=-1)
maxD = F.max(axis=-2)
argmaxE = maxD.argmax(axis=-1)
```

This is the case how I typically solve the discretized version. But now assume instead, that I want to solve `arg max d f(a,b,c,d,e=X)`: Instead of optimally chosen `e` for every other input, `e` is a fixed and given (of size AxBxCxD, which in this example would be `10x10x100x10`). I have troubles solving this.

My naive approach was

```
X = np.tile(np.arange(0,10)[newaxis,newaxis,:,newaxis], [10,10,1,10])
maxX = F[X]
argmaxD = maxX.argmax(axis=-1)
```

However, the huge surge of memory that crashes my IDE implies that `F[X]` is apparently not what I was looking for.

**Performance is key.**

Comment: it seems what you want is something like: `np.argmax(np.max(F, axis=-1), axis=-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do it like this, but maybe there's a better way..

```
n = 10
F = np.tile(np.arange(0,n,0.1)[None,None,:,None,None], [n, n, 1, n, n])
X = np.tile(np.arange(0,n)[None,None,:,None], [n, n, 1, n])

a,b,c,d = np.ogrid[:n,:n,:n,:n]
argmaxD = F[a,b,c,d,X].argmax(axis=-1)
```

---

Above `X` doesn't occupy the whole space, as we discussed in the comments. If you would like to choose `e` for all `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` you could do e.g.:

```
X = np.tile(np.arange(0,n,0.1).astype(int)[None,None,:,None], [n, n, 1, n])
a,b,c,d = np.ogrid[:n,:n,:100,:n]
argmaxD = F[a,b,c,d,X].argmax(axis=-1)
```

Also, notice that instead of `tile` you could make use of broadcasting. But then `F[a,b,c,d,X]` has a singular dimension so you should provide something like `axis=3`:

```
X = np.arange(0,n,0.1).astype(int)[None,None,:,None]
a,b,c,d = np.ogrid[:n,:n,:100,:n]
argmaxD = F[a,b,c,d,X].argmax(axis=3)
```

Comment: Without fully digesting what's happening here: my old `argmaxD` (from standard maximization) had shape `(10L, 10L, 100L)`, while the `argmaxD` you provide has shape `(10L, 10L, 10L)`. As it's supposed to be the optimal maximizer given `(a,b,c)`, which have shape `(10, 10, 100)`, this cannot be correct.

Comment: @FooBar, I had already noticed the different size in one of the dimensions, but that's the result of choosing `X = np.tile(np.arange(0,n),...`. I guess you should just input the `0.1` stepsize. Then you should also use `np.ogrid[:n, :n, :100, :n]`

Comment: `0.1` stepsize gives `IndexError`, since it needs to be integer. `X` needs to contain integer values for what we selected out of the grid for `e`. `e` contains `100` elements. That means, we need to select between `(0, 99)` for `e`, right? So then I tried `X = np.tile(np.arange(0,100)...)`, but I get an `IndexError`... I know I'm making a mistake, I can't just spot it.

Comment: @FooBar, oh right they're supposed to be indices.. Well indices for `e` can only be 0-9 because that dimension is only length 10. I guess you need to choose `X` differently. Maybe `floor(arange(0, 10, 0.1))`?

Comment: With `X = np.tile(np.arange(0.1,10)[newaxis,newaxis,:,newaxis], [10,10,10,10])`, I get shape `(10,10,100,10)`. Then adjust `ogrid[:n, :n, :100, :n]`, and the rest works. I'm still curious why this is so complicated. Especially compared to Matlab, where I started doing most of my matrix algebra.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my idea to solve this.

```
from itertools import product, starmap

f = lambda a,b,c,d,e : d / e

args_iterable = product([1],[2],[3],range(1,1000),range(1,1000))

max_val, max_args = max(starmap(lambda *args: (f(*args), args) , args_iterable))

print max_args
```